# someone who can't admit mistakes or is always right? slang

Tags: slang, epithet-requests

A word for someone who refuses to admit to being wrong or mistaken about anything, even as minor as a typo?

Comment: I'm convinced the word is "Covfefe" tweeted by President Trump who then stated that it's a real word that few people know.

Answer (score 0):

Slang dictionary suggests that the word you might be looking for is "klink"

"A pompous over confident infallible person."

Urban Dictionary [definition 3](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=klink), likely derived from Colonel Klink in the *Hogan's Heroes* TV series.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thanks for your answer. Please add a link.